# C Macro to prefix and suffix a string?

Tags: c, colors, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to clean up my code for colouring strings. Here's what I have to prefix a red ANSI colour to a string, then suffix it with a reset colour.

```
#define GET_RED_TEXT(x) “\x1B[31m” x “\x1B[00m”
```

However, when I try use it...

```
src/util.c:18:15: error: expected expression
        char *temp = GET_RED_TEXT("error: ");
                     ^
includes/util.h:14:25: note: expanded from macro 'GET_RED_TEXT'
#define GET_RED_TEXT(x) “\x1B[31m” x “\x1B[00m”
                        ^
src/util.c:22:14: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        va_end(arg);
                    ^
                    ;
```

Any ideas whats up with my macro?

Comment: Well this is embarassing, my friend uses a Mac and sent me this code. I copied it and pasted it, we both spent a good 10 - 15 minutes trying to figure out what was up with it.

Comment: Sent it to you... in a Word document?

Comment: Skype, they seem to have changed their whole formatting thing too, so perhaps that's why.

Comment: Also, voting to close as typo, as the solution has nothing to do with the question's title or content.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I agree, flagged it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macro has smart quotes in (`“`, `”`) not real quotes (`"`).

Also, as a matter of good practice, put a bracket round the definition, and `x`, e.g.:

```
#define GET_RED_TEXT(x) ("\x1B[31m" (x) "\x1B[00m")
```

Comment: What are smart quotes, how do you type them? I know in LaTeX you just use `\`\`some text''`

Comment: ahh, my mac friend sent me this snippet and lazily copy/pastad it. Cheers!

Comment: @iharob: smart quotes are quotes where the open and close quote look different.

Comment: I know how they look, and I know how to input them with LaTeX just `\`\`Text''`, but I thought the OP copied the text and pasted it, that's why I asked, and I was right.

Comment: OIC. Normally corrupted by MS Word or oh-so-clever email software.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have copied the code from some place and the double quotes are not valid  try this

```
#define GET_RED_TEXT(x) "\x1B[31m" x "\x1B[00m"
```

copy and paste it into the editor please.

Note, that the your code is not highlighted properly.